# Android app_name with special characters/diacritics

Tags: android, xml, react-native

I have an android app built in React Native.
In `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` i have the app name with diacritics, but app is crashing while opening because of the special characters **í** and **ó**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Parkovací zóny Brno</string>
</resources>
```

This name works, but i need it to be localized as above:

```
<string name="app_name">ParkovaciZonyBrno</string>
```

I've tried to use unicode U+00F3 or with excaping \U+00F3 or html entity, but nothing works.

Can you please point me to the right direction how can i use diacritics in the app name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the version of Flipper that currently ships with React Native. The solution is to update the Flipper version.

The Flipper version is defined in `android/gradle.properties`. Change the line which says `FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0` to `FLIPPER_VERSION=0.145.0`.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34066

Answer (score -1):

You can display each of these characters like this without giving up your UTF-8 encoding.

To display "é" use `&#233;` or `&eacute;`

To display "á" use `&#225;  or` á`

To display "í" use `&#237;`  or `&iacute;`

In each of these cases you write &...; in place of the letter, including the semicolon. So to write the word "éclair" you would use éclair.

For more symbols you can find a pretty complete reference https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp.

Comment: As i said, i've tried html entities, it actually change the name properly, but then app will crash immediately.